# Setting the maximum connection limit on CloudSQL instance

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

While checking the documentation for GCP CloudSQL, I found that max allowed connections is 4000 for the MySQL second Generation instance. Is there a way by which I can set my max allowed connections limit on the DB.

In the available flags the max_concurrent_connections flag is not available.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [hard limit that depends on the machine type](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#limits). In [some scenarios](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-cloud-sql-discuss/connection$20limit|sort:date/google-cloud-sql-discuss/pUOOZUs1blw/-cmiiGcxEAAJ), you might be able to implement [connections pools](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#connections)